# jQuery $.getScript() : script loaded but not bound

Tags: jquery

I try to dynamically load many scripts in my page

```
function loadAdditionalScripts()
{   
    $.when(
        $.getScript('modules/cap_Maps/include/js/functions.messages.js', function(data, textStatus){
            console.log("Load 'modules/cap_Maps/include/js/functions.messages.js' complete."); //success
        }),
        // ... More scripts
    ).done(function(){
        return true;
    });
}
```

In Firebug log, I can see my AJAX request returns my script correctly in response.
But my success message (`Load 'modules/cap_Maps/include/js/functions.messages.js' complete.`) isn't print in Firebug.

When I try to use a function declared in the script which is loaded I have an error : `myFunction is not defined`.

And I can't find a way to debug or to fix this problem.

Comment: Consider adding an error handler using `.error()` or `.ajaxError()` to determine whether there was an error.

Comment: I have no ajax error. And if I look my AJAX response, there is my script in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because I have a syntax error in the script I tried to load (but no syntax error in Firebug).